# MessageBox missing Assembly

Tags: c#, winforms

I am `using System.Windows.Forms`(`.MessageBox`)`;`
I also added the required reference in VS.

Why do I get a missing assembly (not found in `System.Windows`) error in this line?

```
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("An error occured: " + error.Problem);
```

Comment: Its `System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox` not `System.Windows.MessageBox`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you want to use a MessageBox from the `System.Windows.Forms` class but you only wrote `System.Window`.
Change your code to

> System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("An error occured: " + error.Problem);

and it will work.

Answer (score 4):

[`System.Windows.MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messagebox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is for WPF applications. You need [`System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

So your code should be:

```
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("An error occured: " + error.Problem);
```

Or you can include a using statement:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

and then just use:

```
MessageBox.Show("An error occured: " + error.Problem);
```

Comment: I've tried your second solution before, but it didn't seem to work.  #_#

Comment: @0rube, are you getting any error ? have you placed the `using` directive at the top of your class, along with other `using` directives ?